# rails_admin+cancan2 unauthorized access in dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rails-admin

Using rails_admin + cancan2 i have a problem with the ability.
according with the official docs https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan i have configured my ability.rb file:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, :all

    if user
      if user.has_role? :admin
        can :access, :all
      end
      if user.has_role? :manager
        can :access, :rails_admin   # grant access to rails_admin
        can :dashboard              # grant access to the dashboard
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the problem is using cancan version 1.6 works fine, but using cancan 2 the "manager" is unauthorized to access in the dashboard, but he is authorized to access in rails admin. So:

```
can :access, :rails_admin   #work
can :dashboard     #don't work
```

if i go in localhost:3000/admin the error is the classic

```
CanCan::Unauthorized in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard
```

but if i go localhost:3000/admin/models it works, so the

```
can :dashboard     #don't work
```

doesn't works

can you help me?

Comment: are all of the dashboard controller actions restful?

Comment: i dpn't know, how can i discover it?

Comment: Is everything normal like :index, :show, :create or are there other actions in the controller that you are trying to render?

Comment: I think the actions are normal resfull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
can :dashboard, :all
```

should work.

After displaying dashboard, you need another patch for work with CanCan 2.0

```
# patch for CanCan 2.0
module RailsAdmin
  module Extensions
    module CanCan
      class AuthorizationAdapter
        def authorize(action, abstract_model = nil, model_object = nil)
          @controller.current_ability.authorize!(action, model_object || abstract_model && model_name(abstract_model.model)) if action
        end
        def authorized?(action, abstract_model = nil, model_object = nil)
          @controller.current_ability.can?(action, model_object || abstract_model && model_name(abstract_model.model)) if action
        end
        private
        def model_name(model)
          model.to_s.underscore.pluralize.to_sym
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen something like

```
can :dashboard
```

The normal structure of the can directive is "can :action, :object" (or class)

So, from what I understand from your question, I assume you should change this into

```
can :manage, :dashboard
```

if you want to assign "all rights"

Comment: i have found can :dashboard the official docs. I have never seen this syntax, but it works with cancan1.6

Comment: I see this indeed in the rails_admin doc. I guess it's a typo. I would change it in can :access, :dashboard. Sounds most logical. And maybe, indeed in the previous version this did work...

Comment: before asking in this forum i have just tried to use :access and :manage but it not works

Comment: Sorry, but then I won't be able to help you. Maybe raise an issue on the github rails_admin forum?

Comment: Thanks, i can try to open an issue